# jQuery plugin: how to pass element reference to callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this

TL;DR: I have `jQuery.myPlugin`

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(param, callback){
  //...which does some operations to each member of collection
  //obtained by $('.someclass').myPlugin()
  //that are represented with this variable
}
```

how to pass **`this`** variable - single node reference - to `callback` when plugin's job is done? Like this:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(param, callback){
  //...
  //...
  //when job is done:
  callback.call(this);
}
$('.someclass').myPlugin(options, function(arg){ 
  //I need arg to be this variable from plugins definition...
})
```

Just to mention, whatever I pass to `callback.call(somevar)`, somevar is not available in executed anonymous callback function.

Comment: `//when job is done:
  callback(this);` call the callback directly. or `//when job is done: callback.call(this, this);` see the `.call` docs.

Comment: @vinayakj write and answer, that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//when job is done:
callback(this);
```

call the callback directly. or use

```
//when job is done: 
callback.call(this, this);
```

see the `.call` API [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: that's it. Waiting for time limit to accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If callback is definitely a function, you should try

```
callback(this);
```

Comment: That's the first thing I've tried: no results, can't catch anything in nonymous function.

Comment: This is correct answer. @Miloshio It will work as expected. If it doesn't work for you then show how you use callback function.

Comment: Is the function being called at all? Just not getting 'this' passed?

Comment: Function is being called and, what is `this` in `callback.call(this)` doesn't show in anonymous function passed as callback.